# ERROR 000837: The workspace is not the correct workspace type. in arcpy.management.CreateVersion

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I am trying to create version in branch versioning enabled feature service.

But my simple code is failing.

```
# Import system modules
  import arcpy

 # Set local variables
 inWorkspace = "https://<host>:6443/arcgis/rest/services/myfolder/myservice/FeatureServer"
parentVersion = "sde.DEFAULT"
versionName = "GPVersion"

# Execute CreateVersion

arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
arcpy.management.CreateVersion(inWorkspace, parentVersion, versionName, "PUBLIC")
```

While running in the ArcGIS Pro it gives below error, although there is no other version with same name present there.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 23043, in 
CreateVersion
raise e
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 23040, in 
CreateVersion
retval = 
convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CreateVersion_management(*gp_fixargs((in_workspace, 
parent_version, version_name, access_permission), True)))
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 
512, in <lambda>
return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 001148: Cannot create a version with the specified 
name.
Failed to execute (CreateVersion).
```

[image]

Again when I am trying to run it as standalone Python script, it gives different error.

```
    arcpy.CreateVersion_management(inWorkspace, parentVersion, versionName, "PUBLIC")
    File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 23043, 
    in CreateVersion
    raise e
    File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 23040, 
    in CreateVersion
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CreateVersion_management(*gp_fixargs((in_workspace, parent_version, version_name, access_permission), True)))
    File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", 
    line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000837: The workspace is not the correct workspace type.
    WARNING 000379: The value may not be valid because of empty domain or does not exist 
    in the domain
    Failed to execute (CreateVersion).
```

[image]

Again it is working with geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro with same parameter.

[image]

it is quite annoying that same code behave different in different environment. I checked other question with same type of problem but could not get solution. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or it is bug in ArcGIS.

Comment: It''s confusion to say that it doesn't work in Pro but it works in Pro. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate the distinct characteristics for each environment, including the client (with release), type of connection, and result. If you think this is a bug, you should contact Tech Support.

Comment: I have updated question for better understanding.